# css arranging div's in left order

Tags: html, css, positioning

I had a div in my web application which had unlimited width users can slide it.. with dynamic height ( means height according to the user's screen ). Inside that I have to scatter some div's . you can get the clear idea / sample from here

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/3fmVF/2/embedded/result/)
| [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/3fmVF/2/)

Now its floating left to the first div .. But I need some thing as

The first div will come in left top , then the second one at the bottom to the first one. Then if got enough space for third one then it must came under two or in top.

you can get some more idea here

```
+------------------------------------------------------------
|     
|  div 1         div 3      div 6
|
|                 div 4
|
|
|  div 2        div 5
|
|
+--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried float:left , display:block .... not working ....

Comment: I don't "think" this is possible mate

Comment: I've not done this exact layout but you could try http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force all divs with float:left, then use a
`<div style='clear:both'></div>` to create a new line of divs

http://jsfiddle.net/3fmVF/3/

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply and I tried like this and can keep the div's to the left but all div's are coming down to each div see http://jsfiddle.net/3fmVF/5/

Comment: because you forgot to add the class "clear" to the second div, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/3fmVF/7/

Comment: thanks fir the help ....  but the problem is all div's are loading dynamically .. not as pre defined... so cant give ( cant specify the second div ) second div to clear class ... please help .. :(

Comment: then please specify better you question, if you want that all divs stays automatically use the float left thing, if you want a div that occupies all the page just don't give any width or float property